# symfony doctrine migrations with multiple entity managers

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to make SaaS application and for this purpose created multiple entity managers and corresponding connections by following [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) but running `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --em=customer` command results in exception `The "--em" option does not exist.`. I know that i can change `doctrine_migrations.yaml` parameter called `em` but that`s not a solution considering that number of entity managers can grow. Is there any workaround to go with?

doctrine.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            tenant:
                url: '%env(resolve:TENANT_DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                wrapper_class: App\Service\Config\Database\Connection

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true

        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: false
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    Shared:
                        mapping: true
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Shared'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Shared'
                        alias: Shared

            tenant:
                connection: tenant
                auto_mapping: false
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    Tenant:
                        mapping: true
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Tenant'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Tenant'
                        alias: Tenant
```

`App\Service\Config\Database\Connection` class is just a wrapper that can change connection's parameters on fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far answer is: docs are [outdated](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/14101), `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` v3.1 will probably solve it, but it relies on `doctrine/migrations` library to release v3.1 (as mentioned in [issue](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/pull/364)), and so far only solution is [this](https://jmsche.fr/en/blog/upgrade-doctrine-migrations-from-2-x-to-3-0) workaround with command wrappers but it requires tweaks with configuration (`YamlFile` in article expects doctrine style config and not symfony's)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write for each Connection an config.yml and then you can use `php bin/console doctrine:migration:diff --configuration=<path-to-config>/config.yml` to migrate your database.

```yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'DoctrineMigrations': 'src/MigrationsDefault'
    connection: default
```

```yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'DoctrineMigrations': 'src/MigrationsTenant'
    connection: tenant
```

Comment: Not wokring as i can say. Because --configuration expects doctrine configuration and not symfony's and results in `Migrations configuration key "connection" does not exist.` same for `em` parameter

Answer (score 0):

I'm solving the problem of migrations for different EntityManagers (each one with a seperate DB connection), with 2 simple shell scripts.

```
generate-migrations.sh [name-of-entity-manager]
```

Takes as argument the name of entity manager.
After running doctrine:migrations:diff --em=name-of-entity-manager it moves all generated migrations to a subfolder: migrations/name-of-entity-manager

```
execute-migrations.sh [name-of-entity-manager]
```

Takes as argument the name of entity manager.

Before running doctrine:migration:migrate, it moves all migrations from the subfolder migrations/name-of-entity-manager to the configured/default migrations folder (migrations)

When it is done with migrations (doctrine:migration:migrate --em=name-of-entity-manager), it moves all the migrations back to the sourcefolder migrations/name-of-entity-manager.

Seems to work fine.

The --em parameter was restored in doctrine migration bundle version 3.2.